# How can I make a tooltip extend outside its table cell?

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4

I am unable to find a solution for Tooltip. When I hover the row, the tooltip for icons seems cut from the top. And this only seen in 1st row of the table, whereas in other rows of the table it seems fine. See attachment.

[image: Tooltip]

Comment: is this using ng bootstrap?

Comment: Please provide more detail about your code in your question.

Answer (score 1):

it's because it's "under" the top of the table body's scroll container.

you haven't specified what library you're using, but if this is ng bootstrap, set the container to body...

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-secondary"
  ngbTooltip="Vivamus sagittis lacus vel augue laoreet rutrum faucibus." container="body">
```

from here: https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/tooltip/examples

if it's not ng bootstrap, you'll have to find the equivalent for whatever your lib is.